# NTLM authentication for Microsoft Dynamics NAV '18 web service from Node.js fails

Tags: node.js, ntlm, ntlm-authentication, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I've been struggling with authenticating to `NAV '18` from `Node` server.
NTLM authentication works fine from POSTMAN but not from Node. I've already tried using `'Authorization: NTLM', 'username:password'` as a header of my request, as well as some NTLM libraries such as httpntlm with no luck.

Is there an actually working example of ntlm authentication with username and password? Changing windows credentials to NAVUserPassword is not an option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `httpntlm` module I wrote a few years ago:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpntlm

```
var httpntlm = require('httpntlm');

httpntlm.get({
    url: "https://www.url.to.nav.com",
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    workstation: '',
    domain: ''
}, function (err, res){
    if(err) return err;

    console.log(res.headers);
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Is password encrypted when sent?

Comment: The password is hashed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple server instances for NAV with the same backend database. I use this for creating an instance for use with Azure Active Directory, without effecting our internal Active Directory based users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/how-to--create-a-microsoft-dynamics-nav-server-instance